# ArrayOut of Bound exception in Android while working with grid view

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
     view = _lInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_apps_checked_item, null);
     CheckBox chkUhkItem = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.all_apps_cb);
     chkUhkItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             _iCheckBoxClick.onCheckCliked(isChecked,_apps.get(position).packageName,position);
         }
      });
      return view;
}
```

And my public interface is

```
public interface ICheckBoxClick{
    void onCheckCliked(boolean isChecked,String packageName,int pos);
}
```

And my implementation is for ICheckBoxClick is:

```
//Apps Seletion Dialog
public void showSeletionAppsDialog(Context actityCtx,
        final String cat_name, final IAddSubItemsClick iAddSubItemsClick) {
    final ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(actityCtx);
    dialog.setTitle("Select Apps =>" + cat_name);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.all_apps_grid);
    GridView appsGrid = (GridView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.all_apps);
    ICheckBoxClick icheckBoxClick = new ICheckBoxClick() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckCliked(boolean isChecked, String pkgName, int pos) {
            if (isChecked) {
                selected.add(cat_name + "," + pkgName);
            } else {
                selected.remove(pos);
            }
        }
    };
    appsGrid.setAdapter(new AllAppsSelectionAdapter(actityCtx,
            icheckBoxClick));
}
```

`Selected.remove(pos)` is throwing Array out of bound exception.

```
12-30 12:59:18.106: E/AndroidRuntime(13028): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 1
12-30 12:59:18.106: E/AndroidRuntime(13028):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
12-30 12:59:18.106: E/AndroidRuntime(13028):    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:403)
```

From the above logs I understood that size of ArrayList is only 1 and you are trying to remove & element. Hence arrayOutOfBoundException. I don't have better solution to fix this.

Comment: It's written there "Invalid index 7, size is 1". Debug your code.

Comment: Yes there is only one element and am trying to remove 7th element ,I need a suggestion how to resolve this..

Comment: @ARP you can get the array count and compare it with index before doing any operations on array, or you can wrap all these statements in a try catch block.

Comment: @ARP posted my answer check it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use remove(Object object) method instead remove(int index)
```

The problem is here..

```
    if (isChecked) {
            selected.add(cat_name + "," + pkgName);
        } else {
            selected.remove(pos);
        }
```

you are adding `String` to `Araylist`...but you are removing int from the `Arraylist`..if you added first item in listview..there is only one item..if you added 5th item then there is two elements..if you remove 5th element you are removing `remove(5)` but there are only two elements..so use `remove(object object)` method instead `remove(int index)` change your code like..

```
 if (isChecked) {
            selected.add(cat_name + "," + pkgName);
        } else {
            selected.remove(cat_name + "," + pkgName);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the object that calls `getView()` has passed in unexpected position index.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution.
Rather than looking at indices of arraylist ,it is better to remove objects from array list by specifying specific object.